# Migrating / Redirecting parts of my ASP.NET site to new version

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis-7

I am currently supporting an existing ASP.NET MVC web-site that was written by another developer.  Many parts of the site were upgraded to more modern frameworks,  and I would like to redirect users to the new site where possible.  However, there are still some pages that will have to continue to be used on the old site until I can finish the migration.

The server is Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.0, .NET 4.5

Let's say the old URL is:  https://www.companysite.com/

The new site is in a virtual directory at: https://www.companysite.com/thenewsite/

What is the best way to selectively redirect users to the new site, where I have those parts built, but also leave the old site accessible for the pages that are not yet transferred to the new design?

For example, I would like to redirect:
https://www.companysite.com/contracts/ to https://www.companysite.com/thenewsite/contracts/

But I can't redirect every path globally.  For example:
https://www.companysite.com/shipping/ can NOT redirect to the new site yet, as I haven't built /thenewsite/shipping/ yet.

Here are some ideas I had, but I could use some guidance as to which one would be best:

- Add a Response.Redirect or a html meta refresh to specific pages in the old site  (Lots of effort)
- Use the URL Rewrite module, with a custom rule (not sure how to do this)

Hopefully this makes sense.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS 7.0 you will probably want to use https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

There are others and it depends on version of IIS. I used to use Helicon Rewrite and as an ISAPI plugin is was at the front of the request pipeline and that's important for performance, you don't want a request to get to a Controller before it's wrong, you'd want to catch it at the Routing at latest.

Whichever URL rewrite tool you use the key is to make them return the correct HTTP code.

A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect. It is cacheable and any bookmarks for this URL should be updated to point to the new URL. A 302 redirect is a temporary redirect. A 303 redirect is the same as a 302 except that the follow-up request is now explicitly changed to a GET request and no confirmation is required

Comment: Thanks.  I just found this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9410364/1279721.  It seems to use some code in global.asax to RedirectPermanent, rather than using the URL Rewrite module.  Basically, you could maintain a Dictionary with the mappings, and redirect from there.  What do you think?  Will this work? @Jeremy-Thompson

Comment: That's a good example of what I've been saying, the request has to go through IIS to get to the Global.asax. You want redirects as early as possible, inside IIS is much faster than in the Global.asax. No call to a managed .net lookup.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, that makes sense.  I am not as familiar with the URL Rewrite module.  Does it have the ability to maintain a list of which URLs to redirect?  Or does it have to rely on pattern matching?  If it is only pattern matching, then I may not be able to do it, as there is no consistent pattern to which URLs to forward.  It's a manual choice at this point.  Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: I won't lie, doing the RegEx's in Helicon Rewrite was HARD. With a bit of research on IIS Rewrite you should be able to find the pattern [WEBSITE]/{thenewsite}/Controller

Comment: You can also do anti-patterns to exclude routes, eg `shipping` would not redirect. Although the regExs/patterns might be harder to setup they are much more powerful than a dictionary lookup and Microsoft developed this technology for this exact purpose.